# how to create an adjustable split screen twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I would like to create a split screen using the twitter bootstrap.  Sort of like a 2 containers lined up against each other except I would like the option to change the width of the containers....just like if I was changing the size of my browser.  Is this possible?  I tried to explain using an image.

[explanation in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhxpb.jpg)

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap doesn't include this kind of functionality.

You'll need to use something like the [jQuery Splitter](http://methvin.com/splitter/) plug-in to do what you described.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the [Onsen](http://onsenui.io/) split view. While it's not resizable, it does collapse on narrow screens for a swipe-out menu:

https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons-split-view.html

```
<ons-split-view
  secondary-page="secondary.html"
  main-page="main.html"
  main-page-width="70%"
  collapse="portrait">
</ons-split-view>
```

Unfortunately, Onsen provides a series of ui elements that already exist in bootstrap. So you will have some redundancy there. Like you, I would also prefer a more bootstrap centric solution.

Comment: Can you please provide a code example within your answer? Off-site URLs may go stale, and your answer will become useless.